# Учебник по Delphi

Tags: delphi-7, книги

Добрый день, уважаемые! Подскажите пожалуйста хорошую книгу по Delphi7. Так что бы было всё понятно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от ваших начальных познаний в программировании. Подскажу книгу для начинающих. Сам по ней некогда учился в университете. Книга довольно проста в освоении, но даёт хорошие базовые и затем более продвинутые познания в Delphi. Книга называется "Библия Delphi". Автор Михаил Фленов. Рекомендую купить её, если в серьёз хотите заниматься этим языком. Купить и почитать отзывы можно на [озоне.](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3619629/)
Если же всё-таки финансы ограничены, то можете скачать [здесь.](http://depositfiles.com/ru/files/3cpzeyyby)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Познания в программировании у меня маловаты: изучил HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Почитал отзывы о книге и понял что действительно хорошая книга. Завтра соберусь и куплю данную  книгу.

Comment: книга кстати стоящая, когда занимался делфями, в ней очень много решений и главное описаний!

Comment: А случайно не подскажите нужно ли начинать изучать Delphi из изучения Pascal?

Comment: Я не вижу особого смысла, хотя в университете сначала давали Pascal. Дело в том, что в среде Delphi используется модернизированный язык Pascal, так называемый Object Pascal. Отличия огромны, но есть. Как кому, но мне например второй язык (Delphi) дался значительно легче, чем паскаль. Так что советую спокойно начинать учить по вышеуказанной книге. От паскаля вам толку никакого всё равно не будет.

Comment: Книга неплохая, хотя немного непродуманная. Помню, где-то в середине ее автор ни с того, ни с сего приводить пример очень крутого кода файлового менеджера с использованием WinAPI и пр., хотя до этого про такие вещи не было ни слова. А так написано довольно живо и с юмором, как всегда  у Фленова.